# Which SSL implementation does oracle JVM use?

Tags: security, ssl, jvm

A new openSSL bug was discovered http://heartbleed.com/ i was wondering which SSL implementation oracle jvm is using, its own, gnuTLS, openssl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oracle JVM uses the [Java Secure Sockets Extension](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html), which is part of the JDK.

Comment: """Implemented in 100% Pure Java""" it's within java libraries, thank you!

Comment: @workless No, the SSL/TLS code is not completely Java code, the base implementation is AFIR native code for speed reasons (included in the JRE).